# Tizen. How to update the Children of a Page Content CircleScrollView

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, xamarin.tizen

Creating a wearable Tizen .net application, I create an application that contains a CirclePage variable:

```
private CirclePage _mainPage;
```

I then populate its Content property with some Content:

```
        _mainPage = new CirclePage
        {
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                Children = {
                    new Label { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, Text = "Text!" },
                    button
                }
            }
        };
        _mainPage.CircleSurfaceItems.Add(circleSlider);
        _mainPage.RotaryFocusObject = circleSlider;

        MainPage = _mainPage;
```

At a later point I want to update that page giving it a CircleScrollView:

```
var circleScrollView = new CircleScrollView
            {
                Content = new StackLayout
                {
                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                    Children =
                    {
                        new Label { Text = "scroll!" },
                        new Label { Text = "scroll!" }
                    }
                }
            };
            _mainPage.Content = circleScrollView;
```

Everything is fine to this point.
But say i want to update that List, I notice that after creation/initialization, there doesn't seem to be any methods to update the Children of the Content as Children are read only after created.

Do i need to create a new CircleScrollView and populate the Children each time my list changes?
I suppose i do not have any concrete reason to believe this is inefficient, but other platforms such as apple and android devices seem to provide methods to insert/remove/ or otherwise update a view listing.

Im brand noob with tizen so i apologize in advance if this seems a vapid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
(circleScrollView.Content as StackLayout).Children.Add(...)
(circleScrollView.Content as StackLayout).Children.Remove(...)
```

Check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.layout-1.children?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Layout_1_Children) for more.

Comment: I see i just need to cast the Content instance to a StackLayout and then use its own Children property as the enumerable.